# Run SQL on field value change using previous value and new value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm new to VBA and Access and have inherited a database that needs an improvement.

I have a form in Access that shows a table for editing:
[image]

When the labour rate value in the table is changed I need to run the following query to update another table:

```
update finishedproduct set labourrate = newvalue where labourrate = oldvalue;
```

(Yes the design of this database is bad.)

- Which event can I handle to react to the labour rate changing?
- How can I get the previous value of the field and then the new value
  of the field?
- Something I don't know: When the user changes the labour rate value
  in this grid is the table updated immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the BeforeUpdate event of the form and `OldValue` has the previous value (`Value` is the new value):

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    MsgBox Me.txtLabourRate.OldValue
    MsgBox Me.txtLabourRate.Value
End Sub
```

This happens *just before* the record is updated. You cannot use the `AfterUpdate` event of the Form because the `OldValue` will be the same as the new value.

BeforeUpdate happens *immediately before* the record is updated. The record will be updated - unless the `Cancel` argument is specifically set to `True`. There is the `Current` event for the Form but this happens after the record has been updated and Old/Value will reflect that of the current row - the row they have moved to.

It is possible to use the `AfterUpdate` event of the form, but there is no need: use `BeforeUpdate`. In order to use `AfterUpdate` you would need to use the `Current` event to store the old/current value in a variable.

---

When the field is changed the record is not updated immediately, but the whole record is updated when they move away from the current row (record).

Comment: It's useful to know that but I need to know when the value in the table has been updated, not when it might have been updated.

Comment: I've modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks but from what you say the value still hasn't been updated in the database, because the user hasn't moved away from the current row. Is an event fired when this happens?

Comment: I have modified my answer again to try and emphasise that you do not need to use an `AfterUpdate` event.

Comment: Ok, I am accepting as answer on the assumption that "BeforeUpdate happens immediately before the record is updated. The record will be updated" is true. (You seemed to imply it wasn't when you were talking about the user pressing Escape.) Thanks.

Comment: The record will be updated, unless you specifically set the `Cancel` argument to `True`. However, you should explore. You can always unaccept an answer - I won't be upset ;)